# When defining a class in OWL, how to constrain that an object property must refer to the same individual as another object property?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, manchester-syntax

I'm studying the [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/) and wanted to add my own classes in the context of the used "families" example ontology. So I added a new class `City` as well as a new object property `bornIn`:

```
ObjectProperty: bornIn
   Domain: Person
   Range: City
   Characteristics: Functional
```

Now I want to add another class `X` which represents all persons whose spouse is born in the same city as them. I feel that I have all the "ingredients" ready but I'm not sure how to combine them. It seems that I can use `EquivalentTo` to define the new class by the following two constraints:

1. All individuals of `X` must have a spouse: `hasSpouse some Person`.
2. The birthplace (i.e., an individual of `City`) of the original person and the spouse must be the same. It seems that I can use the property chain `hasSpouse o bornIn` in order to denote the birthplace of the spouse. Also, from the language primer I understood that there is `owl:sameAs` in order to assert that two individuals are the same. The language primer also shows that `value` can be used to refer to one particular individual. But in my case, it seems that I need some kind of placeholder rather than a specific individual, so I'm not sure how to combine this.

The best guess I could come up with is the following but when I add this to my class in Protégé (in the class expression editor), I get the error that the chain operator `o` is unexpected at this position:

```
Class X:
   EquivalentTo: Person and (hasSpouse some Person) and (hasSpouse o bornIn value owl:sameAs bornIn value)
```

[image: Class expression editor with error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something that can be expressed in OWL, but it can be done with by adding a SWRL rule, assuming you have a class `SpouseBornInSameCity`:

```
hasSpouse(?x, ?y) ^ bornIn(?x, ?z) ^ bornIn(?y, ?z) -> SpouseBornInSameCity(?x) ^ SpouseBornInSameCity(?y)
```